# Calculation of min/max/avg transaction duration is missing the ID of the shortest transaction in output

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a log file which I must parse with unix commands.

I need to calculate time differences between rows, and at the end I need to show the MIN, MAX & AVG time between transactions and the MIN's ID number.

My script is doing everything I wrote accept for the MIN's ID number, and I can't figure why.

- Log file example:

  ```
  03/22 08:51:01.050 INFO :1000 :.main: *************** RSVP Agent started ***************
  03/22 08:51:01.532 INFO :1001 :...locate_configFile: Specified configuration file: /u/user10/rsvpd1.conf WARNING
  03/22 08:51:01.405 INFO :1002 :.main: Using log level 511
  03/22 08:51:01.970 INFO :1003 :..settcpimage: Get TCP images rc - EDC8112I Operation not supported on socket.
  03/22 08:51:01.837 INFO :1004 :..settcpimage: Associate with TCP/IP image name = TCPCS
  03/22 08:51:02.100 INFO :1005 :..reg_process: registering WARNING process with the system
  03/22 08:51:02.524 INFO :1006 :..reg_process: attempt OS/390 registration
  03/22 08:51:02.748 INFO :1007 :..reg_process: return from registration rc=0
  03/22 08:51:06.624 TRACE :1008 :.....starting_transaction: calling API: status: START
  03/22 08:51:06.123 INFO :1009 :...read_physical_netif: index #0, interface VLINK1 has address 129.1.1.1, ifidx 0
  03/22 08:51:06.524 INFO :1010 :...read_physical_netif: index #1, interface TR1 has address 9.37.65.139, ifidx 1
  03/22 08:51:06.367 INFO :1011 :...read_physical_netif: index #2, interface LINK11 has address 9.67.100.1, ifidx 2
  03/22 08:51:06.748 INFO :1012 :...read_physical_netif: index #3, interface LINK12 has address 9.67.101.1, ifidx 3
  03/22 08:51:06.965 INFO :1013 :...read_physical_netif: index #4, interface CTCD0 has address 9.67.116.98, ifidx 4
  03/22 08:51:06.010 INFO :1014 :...read_physical_netif: index #5, interface CTCD2 has address 9.67.117.98, ifidx 5
  03/22 08:51:06.050 INFO :1015 :...read_physical_netif: index #6, interface LOOPBACK has address 127.0.0.1, ifidx 0
  03/22 08:51:06.100 INFO :1016 :....mailslot_create: creating mailslot for timer
  03/22 08:51:06.724 INFO :1017 :.....ending_transaction: calling API: status: END
  03/22 08:51:06.970 INFO :1018 :.....mailslot_create: creating mailslot for RSVP
  03/22 08:51:06.160 INFO :1019 :....mailbox_register: mailbox allocated for rsvp
  ```
- My script:

  ```bash
  for i in log-file.txt
  do
    cat log-file.txt | grep -E "starting_transaction|ending_transaction" >> transactions.txt | awk '{print $2}' <transactions.txt >global-time.txt

    awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }' <global-time.txt >seconds-time.txt

    awk 'NR > 1 { print $0 - prev } { prev = $0 }' <seconds-time.txt >difference-time.txt

    awk '{print $4}' <transactions.txt >trans-id.txt | paste difference-time.txt trans-id.txt > diff-transid.txt

    awk '{if(min==""){min=max=$1 $2}; if($1>max) {max=$1 $2}; if($1<min) {min=$1 $2}; total+=$1; count+=1} END {print "avg " total/count," | max " max," | min " min " | minID " $2}' <diff-transid.txt >final-answer.txt

  done
  ```
- The result I get:

  ```
  avg 11.1467  | max 99.1  | min 0.1 | minID
  ```
- The result I need:

  ```
  avg 11.1467  | max 99.1  | min 0.1 | minID 1017
  ```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please try to expand the explanation further. I _assume_ if you say you want to calculate "time differences between rows", it is not between adjacent rows but between `starting_transaction` and `ending_transaction` messages, and the `minID` is the ID of the `ending_transaction` message with the shortest duration? Also, since you have a date and time field, can a transaction cross over into the next day, which would require more advanced date processing? Does `03/22` stand for March 22nd, or "March 2022"?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be completely implemented in an `awk` script, which will be uch more efficient than using shell loops for text processing. I would recommend the following program (let's call it `analyze_timing.awk`):

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function timediff(start,end,    stfld,endfld,diff) {
    split(start,stfld, /:/)
    split(end,  endfld,/:/)

    if (endfld[1]<stfld[1]) {
        diff=(3600*(endfld[1]+24) + 60*endfld[2] + endfld[3])
    }
    else {
        diff=(3600*endfld[1] + 60*endfld[2] + endfld[3])
    }

    diff -= (3600*stfld[1] + 60*stfld[2] + stfld[3])
    return diff
}


$5 ~ /^:\.+starting_transaction/ {laststart=$2;next}

$5 ~ /^:\.+ending_transaction/ {
    n_transact++
    duration=timediff(laststart, $2)
    avg+=duration
    
    if (n_transact==1) {
        shortest=duration
        longest=duration
        min_id=substr($4,2)
    }
    else {
        if (duration<shortest) {
            shortest=duration
            min_id=substr($4,2)
        } else if (duration>longest) {
            longest=duration
        }
    }
}

END {
    printf("avg: %f | max: %f | min: %f | minID: %d\n", avg/n_transact, longest, shortest, min_id)
}
```

This will first define a function `timediff()` to calculate the elapsed time between two timestamps as shown in your example. For simplicity, it assumes that a transaction will take less than 24h.

It will then check if the 5th field of a line starts with `starting_transaction` after a `:` and an arbitrary number of `.` and record the time in a variable `laststart`. If the 5th field similarly starts with `ending_transaction`, it will calculate the difference to `laststart` and fill variables for calculating min/max/average. If it was the shortest transaction so far, the ID will be recorded in `min_id`.

At the end, the program prints the summary as desired.

You would call it as

```
awk -f analyze_timing.awk log-file.txt
```